# passing an array without being a copy c#

Tags: c#

How can i pass an array without making a copy of it?
I have:

```
private readonly IList<GameObjectTemplate> mMapGameObjects;

    public GameObjectTemplate[] GetObjects(GameObjectType type)
{
    List<GameObjectTemplate> tempObjects = new List<GameObjectTemplate>();

    for (int i = 0; i < mMapGameObjects.Count; i++)
    {
        if (mMapGameObjects[i].Type == type)
        {
            tempObjects.Add(mMapGameObjects[i]);
        }
    }

    return tempObjects.ToArray();
}
```

So i want to select only my objects of a certain type and return the same array without being a copy.Is it possible?

Comment: Do you need a collection? You could use a query instead without persisting it: `return mMapGameObjects.Where(g => g.Type == type);`

Comment: When *pass* a C# *array*, you are *not* creating a copy, just passing a reference. Your code, on the other hand, does quite something different from passing an array. Please think about and specify what you mean by "it" in your text "... copy of it".

Comment: Are you trying to delete all objects that are not of the given type from the original array? Your code returns a new array. The objects in that array are "originals"--not copies--of objects in mMapGameObjects.

Comment: I am passing this to another class like so: private void Combine()
    {
        GameObjectTemplate[] temp = Level.Map.GetObjects(GameObjectType.Scenery);} so this does not make it copy at all? Performance is my consern.

Comment: @MamaTate: No, it doesn't. However, your call to `ToArray` at the end of the method is what creates a new array that contains only the elements that were in `tempObjects` at that time, and that is not linked to `tempObjects` in any fashion. Likewise, `tempObjects` is a list that is not related to `mMapGameObjects` in any way.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you really need an array as result consider returning `IEnumerable<GameObjectTemplate>`:

```
public IEnumerable<GameObjectTemplate> GetObjects(GameObjectType type)
{
   return mMapGameObjects.Where(m => m.Type == type);
}
```

Comment: Ah thanks i can use a custom enumerator. I am so new to that :D Thanks